# Email Notification after the completion of Biztalk job from the event log

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am wondering if it is possible to send Email after each time a project gets completed, like job complete or failure getting reference from the log file.

I have to access some data from the Oracle database and put the data in to the destination folder using Biztalk. I have to send email after successful completion or Failure to send the data to the destination like Employee data import successful or Employee data import failed.Body of the email should say detail of the import like:

Starting EMP.txt
0 Unchanged, 0 New, 14 Updated, and 5 Errors
EMP.txt Import successful

I am using Biztalk 2010,how can this be done. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please be able to elaborate which project/job/log files you are talking about? The question in itself is very vague and needs some clarification. An example would do nicely.

Comment: Sorry for the previous question. I have added what my problem is.Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an orchestration in BizTalk, you are able to to use Delivery Notification on a send port. For more information, please check this blog post: http://kentweare.blogspot.be/2007/11/biztalk-delivery-notification.html

To put it in layman's terms: the send port will wait for an acknowledgement once the adapter finished sending the message to whatever you've chosen it to be.

If something fails, a `Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.DeliveryFailureException` exception will be thrown, which you can catch in an exception handler.
In case you do not have an exception, the file was written succesfully and you can send a message via the SMTP adapter (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578267.aspx)

In case you do get an exception, this means the file was not written succesfully and you can act accordingly.